# How I set a reference after constructor?

Tags: c++, reference

**I want to set a reference after constructor**

**Example:**

```
class OtherClass
{
public:
    OtherClass() : m_class(Class()){}

    inline void SetData(int data1, int data2)
    {
        //calculate data3

        // I tried:
        m_class = Class(data3);
        //but it doesn't worked
    }

protected:
private:
    Class& m_class;
};
```

**Edit:**

- The Exception is: vector subscript out of range
  because I have glm vectors in the Class.
- I need also call functions in my Class.

**Edit 2:**

**Why I need this?**
Because I have an other class [ExClass] which extends and which have to calulate in constructor:

```
ExClass::ExClass(float d1, float d2, ...) {
//calculate data from given values
SetData(data); 
}
```

Comment: What is the error messag that you have? Do 'Class' have a constructor for (int,int) ?

Comment: Why are you making it a reference to begin with?

Comment: **Thanks for your comments. I simplified the example** and I am using my Vertex Class. **The Exception is: vector subscript out of range**

Comment: (I have glm vectors in my Vertex class)

Comment: This question is very unclear. It is neither clear what you are trying to do nor how it does not work. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] as well as a clear problem statement.

Comment: References can’t be rebound like this. If you want something rebindable, you need to use a pointer (or a smart pointer object), which lets you do both rebinding and assignment by having different syntax (`p = …` vs `*p = …`). The whole point of a reference is that its `p = …` acts like a pointer’s `*p = …`; if you don’t want that, don’t use one.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try it.

Comment: @abarnert Is it also possible to run function of a pointer of a class?

Comment: Why "setData"? Why not  construct in the constructor? What are you trying to accomplish? In other words, why do you think you need this?

Comment: Can't be done. Once a reference variable refers to (aliases) one variable, it always references that variable. That is by design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I assign a new value to a reference, and how can I make a reference refer to something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181372/why-can-i-assign-a-new-value-to-a-reference-and-how-can-i-make-a-reference-refe)

Comment: @JiveDadson Why "setData"?: Because I have an other class which extends and which have to calulate in constructor: OtherClass::OtherClass(glm::vec3 position, float side)
{
 //calculate data from given values
 SetData(data);
}

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do that is to use a pointer and not a reference, as opposed to references - pointers can be set after object creation. Note also that referring (or pointing) to a local variable whose lifetime will end, while still in use, is a bad idea.

Your code may be changed to use a pointer and dynamic allocation or alternatively, `std::unique_ptr`. There are of course other options, these are just examples.

### Option 1 - a pointer and dynamic allocation

```
class OtherClass
{
public:
    OtherClass() : m_class(nullptr){}
    ~OtherClass() {
        delete m_class;
    }

    // block copy and assignment (or implement them)
    OtherClass(const OtherClass&) = delete;
    OtherClass& operator=(const OtherClass&) = delete;

    void setData(int data1, int data2)
    {
        // ... calculate data3 ...

        m_class = new Class(data3);
    }
    bool hasInnerObj() const {
        return m_class; // or: return m_class != nullptr;
    }
    /** call this function only if hasInnerObj() returned true */
    Class& getInnerObj() {
        return *m_class;
    }
private:
    Class* m_class;
};
```

### Option 2 - std::unique_ptr

```
class OtherClass
{
public:
    void setData(int data1, int data2)
    {
        // ... calculate data3 ...

        m_class = std::make_unique<Class>(data3);
    }
    bool hasInnerObj() const {
        return m_class; // or: return m_class != nullptr;
    }
    /** call this function only if hasInnerObj() returned true */
    Class& getInnerObj() {
        return *m_class;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Class> m_class;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. Reference class members (i.e. `m_class`) need to be initialized when object is created.
2. However, both your `Class` instances (one in the constructor, and one in `SetData`) are put on the stack and popped right away, making the reference invalid.

What you need to do is make sure that your class object actually lives through the function call. One way of achieving that is allocating it prior to passing it to the `OtherClass` constructor or `SetData` function:

```
class Class {};

class OtherClass
{
public:
    OtherClass(Class& c) : m_class(c){}

    inline void SetData(Class& c)
    {
        m_class = c;
    }

protected:
private:
    Class& m_class;
};

int main()
{
    Class a;
    OtherClass c(a);

    Class b;
    c.SetData(b); // changes m_class

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example here](http://cpp.sh/94lpb).

Comment: This is not what the OP wants, and I suspect, not what you intend. It changes the `Class a` defined in `main()` to have the contents of `Class b` in `main()`.   I think he wants `Class& m_class` to refer first to `a` and then to `b`, which cannot be done.  In other words, the comment "changes m_class" is wrong. It changes the object that m_class refers to, namely 'a'.

Comment: @JiveDadson Changing `a` (or whatever reference `m_class` currently holds) might or might not be intended. Your guess is as good as mine. Since he is working with `vector3` stuff representing position, I am guessing, at this point, that he wants `Class m_class` and not `Class &m_class`.